# Java Multi thread slower than single thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm testing what happens when you run a code in multiple threads.
Here's what I'm doing:

1) Generate different matrix sizes from 50x50 to 1000x1000 with random values with a Java program I wrote called "Matrix Generator".

2) Run another Java Program with N threads from 1 to 3 max (I have a quad core computer) where each thread calculate the Consistency of the matrix with Floyd Warshall algorythm. I don't parallelize the computation.

The result I get is that as the matrix size increases, the execution time increases considerably when I use multithreading. It is faster when I use a single thread. See the statistics link below.

Why is this happening? Is it because each thread starts its own code and the CPU bus causes a bottleneck because every thread wants to access the RAM?
I used a CPU profiler and what I saw Is that as the matrix size increases, the CPU cache L2 and cache L3 misses increase considerably,

Here's the Java code:

```
public class MultiThreadGraphs {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int nFiles = 50;
    final int matrixSize;
    final int nThreads;

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter matrix size: ");
    System.out.println("Available sizes: 50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 1000");
    matrixSize = reader.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter n threads: ");
    nThreads = reader.nextInt();

    reader.close();

    System.out.println("Reading files..");

    List<int[][]> graphs = readFiles(matrixSize, nFiles);

    System.out.println("Total files: " + graphs.size());

    System.out.println("Running " + nThreads + " threads..");

    try {
        try {
            runThreads(graphs, nThreads);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void runThreads(List<int[][]> graphs, int nThreads) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    Collection<Callable<Long>> callables = new ArrayList<Callable<Long>>();

    for(int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        callables.add(new Callable<Long>() {
            @Override
            public Long call() throws Exception {
                List<int[][]> callableGraphs = graphs;

                Instant start = Instant.now();

                for(int[][] graph: callableGraphs) {
                            FloydWarshall f = new FloydWarshall(graph);
                    f.checkConsistency();
                }

                Instant end = Instant.now();

                Duration timeElapsed = Duration.between(start, end);

                return timeElapsed.toNanos();
            }
        });
    }

    List<Future<Long>> futures = executor.invokeAll(callables);

    SummaryStatistics stats = new SummaryStatistics();

    for(Future<Long> future: futures) {
        stats.addValue(future.get());
    }


    String mean = String.valueOf(stats.getMean());
    double std = stats.getStandardDeviation();

    System.out.println("Execution time: " + (long)Double.parseDouble(mean));

    System.out.println("Mean: " + mean);
    System.out.println("Standard Deviation: " + std);

    executor.shutdown();
}
}
```

Statistics:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wsgn14E9ltCWUHygC926xiz-vHEiENgSoHGzm_-BOa8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If all threads are doing all graphs (which is what it looks like) then you will see exactly this. You will only improve speed if different graphs are processed on different threads.

Comment: Your CPU has only four cores. Instead of creating thousands of threads and working on them in parallel, try creating only 4(8 with SMT) threads in your executorservice.

Comment: @AndreasHartmann I use max 3 threads.

Comment: To add on to what @OldCurmudgeon had to say, the fact that your performance data between multi threaded/single threaded scales equally should be telling you something very important.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon So is it because of the cache misses and the bus shared? I calculate all graphs for every thread but they are separated. So I expect that each thread takes the same time of when I run it with one thread.

Comment: The cache misses are exactly the problem, I don't think the bus is the problem, the shared cache is.

Comment: @JohnF you're not sharing any work, that's why you're not seeing any speed up. There is no problem with the bus or the shared cache or false sharing at all. You are running what a single thread is doing multiple times essentially, so of course there will be no effect.

Comment: @JohnF - Yes. With single thread yu are doing `x` amount of work. With `n`threads you are doing `n * x` work - you cannot expect that to take less time. If you spawn **one thread per graph** you are still doing `x` work but across many threads so you *sould* see a speedup.

Comment: @xTrollxDudex I'm not expecting a speed up. I don't understand why it takes more as the threads increase. I expect to see a time that's more or less the same! With a 1000x1000 matrix and three threads It takes 22 seconds longer.

Comment: The time isn't increasing because the threads are increasing according to your data.

Comment: @xTrollxDudex It is increasing.. but If every thread run its piece of code, why does it takes longer as the threads increase?

Comment: Again, the time taken to complete your operation does not increase because there are additional threads. Allowing for timer errors on order of magnitude the 100 NANOSECOND level, and factoring in potential background skewing, timer latency/granularity, and JIT/GC activity, I'd say that the problem stems from your interpretation of the results rather than the results themselves.

Answer (score 0):

when you are increasing thread and submitting to executor it will take some time if number thread less than the task number as thread will poll and get next task will run using some lock mechanism.

Second thing is all task not starting at same time .Some task will start running after getting thread and you are calling invoke all in that case Suppose task B finished first followed by task C. But task A was still going on.In that case for loop would be waiting for the result of task A to be available as inside invoke all it is doing future.get().

To know the exact time you can create simple thread depending upon cpu core size and note time taking by individual thread without using any lock or other mechanism.Or you can use `ExecutorCompletionService` to get first complete task time.